# How to UNNEST multiple arrays in BigQuery standardSQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, unnest

I am selecting data from Google Bigquery table which includes JSON column. My table has multiple nested arrays, one of the includes two nested levels. 
here is my table schema

[https://imgur.com/UBPKUMx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzD8M.jpg)

My statement is:

```
SELECT 
items.*,
pay.*,
credits.creditnoteid,
credits.id,
credits.total
FROM client_account.invoices,
UNNEST(lineitems) items,
UNNEST(items.tracking),
UNNEST(payments) pay,
UNNEST(creditnotes) credits
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVcJ1.jpg

Unfortunately I get no results...
Can you help me to unnest all of the arrays.

[image]

Comment: I do not think it is related but why are you unnesting `items.tracking`? You do not use it in any part of your query.

Comment: Hi, if I do not unnest items.tracking I can not get all items.* columns. items.tracking will remain JSON format.

Comment: Can you share the table schema? It is very useful if you provide more details possible to reproduce the issue. Check out how to effectively ask questions here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: sure - https://imgur.com/UBPKUMx

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have a dataset with nested arrays to test on it. As a side note when you do `item.*` it will export every field inside items but not traversing them. So you will end up with a column called `tracking` as an array regardless if you had specified `UNNEST(items.tracking)`. If you want to have those field as simple strings you have to do something like `UNNEST(items.tracking) as tracking` and add in the select `tracking.*`. However, I am not sure that the fact you have no result is connected to this.

Comment: `SELECT 
items.*,
tracking.*,
pay.*,
credits.creditnoteid,
credits.id,
credits.total
FROM client_account.invoices,
UNNEST(lineitems) items,
UNNEST(items.tracking) tracking,
UNNEST(payments) pay,
UNNEST(creditnotes) credits` 

same - no results

When I exclude UNNEST(creditnotes) credits

and use this statemnt, it works
`SELECT 
items.*,
tracking.*,
pay.*
FROM client_account.invoices,
UNNEST(lineitems) items,
UNNEST(items.tracking) tracking,
UNNEST(payments) pay`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I did a test on one of my datasets. I think that `creditnotes` is always `null`. Because in my case I get no results when I unnest a column that is always null. You can fix it by using `LEFT JOIN` I modified your query to use left joins but you might be able to tune it better.

```sql
SELECT 
items.*,
tracking.*,
pay.*,
credits.creditnoteid,
credits.id,
credits.total
FROM client_account.invoices
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(lineitems) items
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(items.tracking) tracking
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(payments) pay
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(creditnotes) credits
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I need to get rid of the commas after every line: `FROM client_account.invoices,
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(lineitems) items,
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(items.tracking) tracking,
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(payments) pay,`

Comment: Yes if you want to remove `LEFT JOIN UNNEST(creditnotes) credits` you have to remove the previous comma too. In fact, sometimes you find query with the comma on the next line because it easier to remove parts of it by commenting out the whole line and the query is still valid.

Comment: @Alessandro . . . I didn't realize that you could use `LEFT JOIN` without an `ON` clause in BigQuery.  I learned something.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - it is ONLY allowed for cases when you join on UNNEST'ed array - so implicitly it joins on the same row as array is from. all JOIN work, not just LEFT. In regular cases LEFT JOIN  still requires following ON or USING clause

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant . . . That still seems strange to me.  Postgres, for instance, does not allow a `LEFT JOIN` without an `ON` clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I didn't see this specific behavior being documented - but that's how it works in BigQuery